# Full calendar timeline view resource binding multiple data

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

How to bind multiple content to a single resource in fullcalendar timeline view?

In my code (below), events and resources are added from a single ajax response. And I am trying to add `userdp` also into the resource field along with `title`.

```
resources:response,
events:response,
resourceAreaColumns: [
  {
    field: 'title',
    headerContent: 'Staff details'
  },
  {
    field: 'nhname',
    headerContent: 'NH Name'
  }
],

resourceLabelContent: function(arg) {
    let user = document.createElement('div');
    user.className = "users-contents";
    let username = document.createElement('p');
    let userdp = document.createElement('img');
    userdp.className='userdp';
    user.append(userdp,username);

    if (arg.resource.id == arg.resource.resourceId) {
        username.innerHTML = arg.resource.extendedProps.username;
        userdp.src = arg.resource.extendedProps.userdp;
    }

    let arrayOfDomNodes = [ user]
    return { domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes }},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement makes no sense and isn't necessary. You seem to be trying to compare the resource's ID to its "resourceID" property. But a resource doesn't have a resourceId property, and it's unclear what you were expecting such a comparison to achieve, anyway.

Other than that, the code seemms to be fine.

```
resourceLabelContent: function(arg) {
  let user = document.createElement('div');
  user.className = "users-contents";
  let username = document.createElement('p');
  let userdp = document.createElement('img');
  userdp.className = 'userdp';
  user.append(userdp, username);
  username.innerHTML = arg.resource.extendedProps.username;
  userdp.src = arg.resource.extendedProps.userdp;
  let arrayOfDomNodes = [user];
  return { domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes };
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjNgmKJ